# @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, prisma

I am using prisma, postgres, docker, kubernets.

**npx prisma migrate dev** working.

and **npx prisma generate** produce below output:

```
✔ Generated Prisma Client (2.23.0) to ./node_modules/@prisma/client in 68ms
You can now start using Prisma Client in your code. Reference: https://pris.ly/d/client

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'
const prisma = new PrismaClient()
```

but when I tried to use in my route file produce the error:

new-route.ts

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();
```

my docker file:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --only=prod
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: I think if you copy `COPY prisma ./prisma/` that should work. But I'm a few steps behind you as I can't get the `npx prisma migrate dev` to work with the error message: `Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at auth-postgres-srv.default.svc.cluster.local:5432`

Comment: Just wanted to add my 2 cents to this. Recently spent half a day trying to figure out why my schema changes weren't being reflected when calling Prisma service. Turns out I had to restart the node environment or as I like to do it just restart the whole IDE and voila the changes start reflecting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually don't use docker for this while developing, but I have this issue every time I change something in my `schema.prisma` and have to use `npx prisma generate`. The solution for me is to restart the node application running `npm start` again. Maybe if you restart your containers it might work.

if you are inside kubernets pod then access the pod using terminal then give generate command

```
kubectl exec -it pod_name sh
npx prisma generate
```

Comment: The solution given by Rafiq to run `npx prisma generate` in the pod is likely a bad one - next time the pod is restarted it will fail again. Just [copy the `prisma` dir when building your image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72846505/675721)

Answer (score 16):

I know that this has been marked as solved, but I just wanted to share my setup for anyone interested.

Dockerfile

```
# Build image
FROM node:16.13-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app

# Not sure if you will need this
# RUN apk add --update openssl

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --quiet

COPY ./prisma prisma
COPY ./src src
RUN npm run build

# Production image

FROM node:16.13-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV production

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --only=production --quiet

COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /app/prisma /app/prisma
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /app/src /app/src

USER node

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "generate": "npx prisma generate",
    "deploy": "npx prisma migrate deploy",
    "dev": "npm run generate && nodemon --watch \"src/**\" --ext \"js,json\" --exec \"node src/index.js\"",
    "build": "npm run generate",
    "start": "npm run build && node build/index.js"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "schema": "prisma/schema.prisma"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tsconfig/node16": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.12",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "prisma": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

I run this in Kubernetes. To make things smooth with database and migrations I run an initContainer that runs the `prisma migrate deploy`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: EXAMPLE
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: EXAMPLE
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 100%
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: EXAMPLE
    spec:
      containers:
        image: DOCKER_IMAGE
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: SERVICE_NAME
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - npm
        - run
        - deploy
        image: DOCKER_IMAGE
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: database-migrate-deploy
```

(This is a live service I just copied and stripped away anything non essential)

I hope this could be of use to someone

Comment: how do you run prisma migrations and seed for production? you just ran generate in Dockerfile

Comment: thanks for this, very useful. However, can you explain why you copy your `node_modules` from your build image? Doesn't that overwrite your lean production `node_modules` with all the dev dependencies and bloat your final image?

Comment: @JPLew You're absolutely correct, that statement should not be there. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: @markokraljevic As far as i know `npx prisma generate` only creates the `./prisma/generated` directory. So it makes perfect sense to have that in the Dockerfile.

Comment: And I am facing this error , ``` Error: Unknown binaryTarget linux-arm64-openssl-undefined and no custom engine files were provided```. I have added the binary target in schema.prisma but I couldn’t resolve the error. ``` binaryTargets = ["native", "rhel-openssl-1.0.x"]```

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to copy the `prisma` directory, since generating the Prisma Client requires the `schema.prisma` file. You should copy the whole prisma directory in case you also need the migrations.

Your final Dockerfile should contain the following:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
COPY prisma ./prisma/ 
RUN npm install --only=prod
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct answer, simply copy this folder before running install and it will work

Comment: I was confused why I was receiving the error even though I was copying the `prisma` folder in my Dockerfile. But as you pointed out, it needs to be copied *before* running `npm install`

Answer (score 7):

Here is another way to solve this.

Since the `.prisma` folder is needed by the prisma client as shown in the picture below or in the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/generating-prisma-client#the-prismaclient-npm-package) another way is to make sure it ships with your code. You can do this as follows.

#### Wrong way: ship the generated folder

You would think you can just include the generated files in the image by adding an exception rule for the .prisma folder to your `.dockerignore` (notice the exclamation point)

```
node_modules/
!nodes_modules/.prisma
```

But the query engine used by prisma is [different for each operating system](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-engines/query-engine#the-query-engine-file) so you could run into troubles.

#### Correct way : generate the files with the image

Just add `RUN npx prisma generate` to your Dockerfile before the build command. This way the files are generated during the image creation and you don't have to run the `prisma generate` command on every container. The downside of this method is that your docker image will be larger. If this is an issue you can try with the other answers.

[image: .prisma folder is needed to reference your generated code]

Comment: No need to generate if you copy prisma folder before running `npm install`

Answer (score 3):

For me, I just changed my `start` under `scripts` in my `package.json` so that my app would generate prisma types before running:

```
"start": "npx prisma generate && nodemon server.ts"
```

In production:

```
"start": "npx prisma db push && npx prisma generate && node ./build/server.js"
```

This worked for me – I just wanted to drop this here for anyone who runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue using prisma, mongodb and nextjs while trying to deploy to vercel. I added this to my package json;

```
...
"vercel-build": "npx prisma generate && next build"
...
```

It worked on me.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because docker doesn't install **devDependencies**, which means that it doesn't pick up the **Prisma CLI**.

To remedy this you can add the **prisma CLI** package to your dependencies instead of the **devDependencies**. (Making sure to run **npm install** afterward to update the package-lock.json)

Answer (score 0):

If you use docker compose try this:

1. add this to your Dockerfile

   COPY prisma ./prisma/
2. add the prisma directory to your volume in `docker-compose.yml` file

   ```
   volumes:
     - /app/prisma
   ```

in my case `docker-compose.yml` file will look like this

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: web
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next
      - /app/prisma
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the import adress from: `"@prisma/client"` or `"@prisma/client/edge"`
to: `"../../prisma/generated/client/edge"`

I address the directory where generated folder is created in prisma folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `next js` with `Prisma` and when deploy it to `Vercel` it showed me this error, I just added `"postinstall":"npx prisma generate"` in the scripts of `package.json` file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/22586#issuecomment-1899406921) in Prisma repo, you should add `output` to `schema.prisma`:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "node_modules/.prisma/client"
}
```

‍‍